# C++ Identify first number

Tags: visual-c++

I want to make a program where the user can input many numbers but the program will have to identify if the first four or five numbers is equal to the numbers I've set.

ex.
user inputs 0123456789 
then if first 5 is equal to number I've set. 
Like if ( 01234 = 02134). But all the numbers can be stored in a variable and be displayed again.

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Please make an attempt to program this yourself and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: I dont know how to start. What should I use? Array?

Comment: It sounds like you need to follow some C++ tutorials before trying to write this program. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

this worked. 
kind of.

My code is as follows:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    {
        int mnum [11];
        int ctr;

        for (ctr=0; ctr<=10; ctr++)
        {
            cout << "Enter your mobile number: ";
            cin >> mnum [ctr];
        }
        cout << "Your mobile number is ";
        if (mnum [3] == 1||2 && mnum [4] == 3||1)
        {
            for (ctr=0; ctr<=10; ctr++)
            {
                cout << mnum [ctr];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry. Invalid mobile number prefix." << endl;
            system ("pause");
            return main ();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

but i have to enter each number. how to make it entr it in one go and still have the same results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus and integer division together to get the individual digits.

Here's a mocked up example that will get each digit of a number and print it individually (notice the output number is reversed because of how I am getting the digits):

```
int num = 123456;

while(num > 0) {
    std::cout << num % 10 << ' ';
    num /= 10;
}
```

Output:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```